# JavaScript/VueJS: Check if an Array contains an object with an element that has specific value

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I would like to solve this problem:

I got an Object that contains a property named `specs`. This property contains an `Array` of `Objects` that all have 2 properties:

- name
- value

So my object is like this:

```
Object
-Title
-Date
-Specs [Array]
-- [0] Name: "Power"
-- [0] Value: 5
-- [1] Name: "Weight"
-- [1] Value: 100
```

So - now I would like to check, if my Specs-Array contains an item that has the name "Power". If this is the case, I would like to use the value of this element.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can filter the array based on the name attribute and check if the filter returns a result array , if yes then you can use it with index to get the value.

```js
var data = {specs:[{Name:"Power",Value:"1"},{
    Name:"Weight",Value:"2"},{Name:"Height",Value:"3"}]}
    
var valObj = data.specs.filter(function(elem){
    if(elem.Name == "Power") return elem.Value;
});

if(valObj.length > 0)
    console.log(valObj[0].Value)
```

Answer (score 5):

consider the main object name is objTemp

you can do

```
var arrR = objTemp.Specs.filter(function(ele){
   return (ele.Name == "Power")
});

if(arrR.length)
  //has prop
else
  // no prop
```

Comment: Alright - and how could I access the `ele.value` if `arrR` is true? I would have to get the index of the array`s element in this case, right?

Comment: @SPQRInc arrR  is an array of objects which has Name: "Power" so you can iterate over arrR and get value as arrR[0].Value and so on

Answer (score 0):

```
$.each(object.Specs,function(index,obj){
if(obj.Name === "Power")
var myVar = obj.Value
});
```

Comment: if you use 'some' instead 'each', the loop will stop once you find a valid obj.

Comment: Thanks, wasn't aware of it until now. Very helpful

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [some](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_some.asp) method on array, which will return true or false, depending on your condition, like following:

```
var powerIndex
var doesPowerExist = yourObj.specs.some((spec, index) => {
   var powerIndex = index
   return spec.name == "Power"
})
```

You can use `doesPowerExist` var to decided whether  to use the value of this element.

Comment: Hello,

thanks a lot for your answer. Now `doesPowerExist` would be `true` or `false`, right? How could I access the `value` where `spec.name = "Power"`?

Comment: @SPQRInc I have modified the code, `powerIndex` will be index of corresponding object, use this if `doesPowerExist` is true.